# A program that creates a list of several files

Tags: python, json, list

Data files:

1. file.json - athletes with the indication of the chest number, first and last name
2. result.txt - results of the first attempt
   The time comes in the format "breast_number start HH:MM:SS,dst" and "breast_number finish HH:MM: SS, dst".

What should be displayed as a list:

Result

```
Occupied place|Chest number|First Name| Last Name | Result
  1              23          Jack       Jackson     01:02,32
  2              213         Sam          Stolz     01:56,23
  3              129         Michael    Stivenson   02:09,43
```

Python programming language, version 3.9.

To solve the problem, it is necessary to use the built-in tools / modules of the programming language.

```
file.json
{
  "266": {
    "Name": "Jackson",
    "Surname": "Jack"
  },
  "287": {
    "Name": "Stolz",
    "Surname": "Sam"
  },
  "149": {
    "Name": "Stivenson",
    "Surname": "Michael"
  },
...

result.txt

287 start 16:22:30,000000
287 finish 16:24:08,264286
149 start 13:42:00,000000
149 finish 13:43:49,415825
62 start 11:31:30,000000
62 finish 11:39:42,771429
```

...

You need to write a test task . Please help me, how is it better to do it step by step?

Comment: Your input is JSON file? If yes please prepare the correct input data. It is a very simple task to do, is it?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to import the json module and use the json.loads function to convert the json into a dict. Use loops to parse the dict and look at using f-strings to print the data out to the file.